# Easy way to re-write multiple return statements

Tags: c#

I have some code that's written like so:

```
private double function1()
{
    double result2 = function2();
    if (result2  < 0) { return result2; }

    double result3 = function3();
    if (result3  < 0) { return result3; }

    return 0;
}
```

I need to re-write it such that it has only one return statement.  Is there an easy way to do this?  It strikes me as inefficient to begin with that the same if construct is used twice.  How can this inefficiency be cleaned up?

Comment: With things like this you end up with a lot of conditionals replacing the returns.  I find the result less readable.

Comment: Why only use one return statement? Refactoring will probably lead to inverted if's.

Comment: Why do you have to re-write it to only have one return statement? Is it because of a misguided set of coding guidelines? Have you considered fixing the guidelines instead?

Comment: @Adam S, if you can change `function2` and `function3` to return `null` instead of `0`, you can make it much more readable, see my reply below.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: Sorry, what do you mean by inverted ifs? I googled the phrase and couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @anjruu: this: `if(a == b) { if ( b == c ) { return c;} } return 0;`  could be re-written as: if(a != b) return 0; if ( b == c ) return c; which is quite more readable. In this case it's just a couple of lines. But when you have a lot of nested-ifs and elses you will benefit from inverting them.

Comment: The reason I have to have only one return statement is indeed our coding standards.  Phillips medical coding standards to be exact.

I disagree with the rule personally but that's a battle that will have to be fought later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keep it simple, keep it readable.

```
// direct conversion of your code
private double function1()
{
    double result = 0;

    double result2 = function2();
    if (result2  < 0) 
    {
      result =  result2; 
    }
    else
    {
       double result3 = function3();
       if (result3  < 0) 
       {
         result = result3; 
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

A shorter version, probably easier on the eyes:

```
private double function1()
{
    double result = function2();

    if (result >= 0)   // if (!(result < 0))  to be safe for NaN
    {
       result = function3();
       if (result >= 0) 
       {
         result = 0; 
       }
    }    
    return result;
}
```

---

And

> It strikes me as inefficient to begin with that the same if construct is used twice.

There is nothing inefficient about that. If the pattern was repeated (much) more you could start to think about an extra method or something to aid readability.

Comment: That looks less readable than the original to me. (But it does do what was asked for, of course.)

Comment: @Jon, @Filip: don't be shy to post your own. But I agree it wasn't pretty, added a 2nd version.

Comment: Let's assume the pattern is repeated much more.  How could I possibly decrease all that wrapping?

Comment: The shorter version will have different behaviour if any of the functions returns NaN. The comparison should be if (!(result < 0)), which is rather weird although.

Comment: @Konstantin, thanks. I already felt uneasy about inverting >= on doubles. It doesn't impact on the main discussion though.

Comment: @Adam: If your function2,function3 follow a very strict pattern then  @Scott and @Daniel have interesting answers. Otherwise, well, you just have to grind your teeth sometimes.

Answer (score 12):

A single line solution that doesn't require altering function2/3.  Not particularly readable but interesting:

```
private double function1()
{
    return new Func<double>[] { function2, function3 }
        .Select(c => c()).FirstOrDefault(c => c < 0);
}
```

Personally, I would opt for your original version.

Comment: But, it executes both function2 and function3.  If function3, has side effects, the behavior will be different than before.  At least I think both get executed in this scenario...

Comment: @Chad, since the `Select` returns an enumeration, it will stop processing after satisfing the `First` condition.

Comment: @Daniel, see my comment, I just ran a test, and it indeed does, execute both functions, which changes the behavior of the code.

Comment: @Chad: it executes them both if and only if the function2 returned non-negative result, just like the original code. Note this "Select" thing, it adds laziness to function execution.

Comment: @Jerod, no, it won't.  I just ran a test, and it executed both functions.  Use Daneil's code, and have function2 return a non-zero value, and function3 return an exception.  An exception will be thrown, despite function2 returning a valid value.

Comment: @Jerod, @Daneil, My bad, I can't read...you're right.  I read the condition sign wrong this entire time.  This is in fact a pretty slick solution.

Comment: This is all fine and dandy, but frankly the first thing I would be told to do is to re-write it in a readable way.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
delegate void double DoubleReturningFunction();

private double function1()
{
    DoubleReturningFunction[] functions = { function2, function3 };

    foreach( DoubleReturningFunction function in functions )
    {
       double result = function();
       if( result < 0 ) return result;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was just writing and answer similar to this.  The advantage is that it creates a precedence list of functions.  First try this, then this, then this... until the condition is met.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to re-write it such that it has
>   only one return statement

Are sure you *really* need that? The code shown in your question is perfectly valid and readable to me. Having multiple return statements is certainly not a problem here ; in fact it may be cleaner than all others alternatives (cf. answers).

Comment: I agree for this example. I guess the req is from a coding standard, and that would in general be a good one. A simple function like this one would be sacrificed to prevent multireturn mazes.

Comment: I used to believe the single return "myth" too - but after seeing how much simpler my code is without that rule, I abandoned it long ago.

Comment: @Henk: I don't believe it's a good coding standard rule. There are *loads* of cases where having an extra return statement makes modern code more readable. It was important back in C, where you couldn't use finally blocks to release resources etc... but I don't believe it's an appropriate rule (or even suggestion) in C# code.

Comment: Multireturn mazes versus if/else mazes. The main flow of logic proceding down my screen, versus the main flow of logic proceding down *and* across my screen. The corner cases handled at the top of the a method and forgotten about, versus the corner cases being handled in else blocks all over the place. I feel a community wiki coming on...

Comment: @Jon, @RedFilt, I would not favor such a standard, but I have seen some horrible multi-return code (same area as loops with many break/continue sttmts). The best solution is common sense and insight, but not all shops have enough of that. A strict standard is sometimes the lesser of some evils.

Comment: Better would be to make sure your functions are small enough that if/else mazes or multiple returns aren't likely to trip you up.

Comment: @siride: Yes, that would be nice. But in the real world there are often situations where long sequences of conditions have to be checked. We can't always avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer your original version with multiple returns. But, how about:

```
double ret = function2(); 
if (ret >= 0) 
    ret = function3();
if (ret > 0) 
    ret = 0;
return ret;
```

Comment: +1 this is the simplest way to do it from readability and conciseness without using the select above which only a third of the developers in my office would be able to wrap their head around..

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this...

```
private double function1()
{
    var returnValue = 0;

    double result2 = function2();
    if (result2  < 0) { returnValue = result2; }

    double result3 = function3();
    if (result3  < 0) { returnValue = result3; }

    return returnValue;
}
```

But, that could have side effects, as now both `function2` and `function3` are always called.  So, you'd have to have an else, and increase nesting like

```
private double function1()
{
    var returnValue = 0;

    double result2 = function2();
    if (result2  < 0) { 
        returnValue = result2; 
    } else {    
        double result3 = function3();
        if (result3  < 0) { returnValue = result3; }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

And then, it starts to smell more.  If function 2 and 3 returned null instead of zero, you could just do this...  some casting may be necessary to convert between `decimal?` and `decimal`

```
private double function1()
{
    return function2() ?? function3() ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most readable version I can come up with within the constraints.

```
    private double Function1()
    {
        double result = 1;

        if (result >= 0)
            result = Function2();

        if (result >= 0)
            result = Function3();

        if (result >= 0)
            result = 0;

        return result;
    }
```

This makes it blindingly obvious what is going on. And I'm pretty sure the optimizer will remove the first if expression anyway.

The advantage of this approach is that it is simple to add or re-prioritize the functions.